# Website not responding when sending a GET request using low level c++ networking libraries

Tags: c++, c, linux, http, networking

I am trying to create a program that downloads data from websites using c++ low level networking.
Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#include <arpa/inet.h>



int status, sock;
struct addrinfo hints;
struct addrinfo *servinfo;
int main(int argc, char** argv){
  memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
  hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
  hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
  int MAXDATASIZE = 100;
  char request[] = "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1\n";
  char buf[MAXDATASIZE];
  if((status = getaddrinfo(argv[1], argv[2], &hints, &servinfo)) != 0){
    std::cout << "getaddrinfo: " << gai_strerror(status) << "\n";
    return 2;
  }
  if((sock = socket(servinfo->ai_family, servinfo->ai_socktype, servinfo->ai_protocol)) == -1){
    std::cout << "Error creating socket\n";
    return 2;
  }
  if(connect(sock, servinfo->ai_addr, servinfo->ai_addrlen) == -1){
    std::cout << "Error connecting to host " << argv[1] << " at port " << argv[2] << "\n";
    return 2;
  }
  if((send(sock, request,strlen(request), 0)) == -1){
     std::cout << "Error communicating with website\n";
     return 2;
  }
  if(recv(sock, buf, MAXDATASIZE, 0) == -1){
     std::cout << "Error recciving data from " << argv[1] << " at port " << argv[2] << "\n";
  }
  std::cout << buf << std::endl;
  close(sock);

  freeaddrinfo(servinfo);
}
```

When I try to connect to google, using [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) as the host and 80 as the port, it hangs at the recv() call.To test whether the request was the problem, I connected to google using telnet with the same request, and it worked. I also tried binding netcat to a port on my computer, and then connected to that port using my program. The request was sent properly to netcat, and when I responded with a test message, my program reccived it.

Does anyone know why google isn't sending the data?

I'm using fedora 32, if that might help

Comment: First off, your line endings are incorrect.

Comment: HTTP uses CR + LF, so `\r\n` in C++

Comment: Some servers might complain about missing headers, like `Connection`, `Accept` and `User-Agent`

Comment: Servers might also expect the presence of an empty line, which usually indicates the start of a HTTP Request/Response body, but is usually still present even when no body is sent over

Comment: and also, the buffer size of 100 bytes is too short for one request, by convention, buffers are sized in multiples of 512 (e.g. 1024/2048/4096)

Comment: @expolarity: converted to answer.

Comment: @expolarity: recv and friends only discard data from packet-oriented protocols. TCP is not packeted, and recv won't discard bytes. Just FYI.

Comment: @rici I never experienced a case where recv discarded bytes either, maybe that's just because I'm used to working with buffer sizes of several kilobytes, after rereading the page I linked, it states that "excess bytes **may** be discarded", this does make sense according to what you said, sorry for the misconception and thanks for the clarification

Comment: @Expolarity: UDP is packet-oriented so if you have a UDP socket and your buffer is too short for a packet, the rest of the packet will be discarded. The "D" in UDP stands for "datagram" which is what most if us call packets.

Answer (score 2):

Your software is not hanging. Rather, the server is waiting for an indication that the client has finished sending the headers, which is indicated by sending an empty line. Until the client sends the blank line, the server cannot respond.

Change your request to:

```
char request[] = "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n";
```